# bootstrap left and right glyphicons not showing in carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The two left and right chevron glyphicon are not showing, it works, but it shows a square box for some reason. When I click the positions where the glyhicons are I can scroll through pictures so all that is not right is the appearance of the glyphicons the left and right arrow usually expected are not showing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Association</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-ex">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="5" data-target="#carousel-ex"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img alt="abuja" class="img-responsive" id=
"afCountries" src="img/african-countries/abuja-nigeria.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Abuja, Nigeria</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img alt="accra" class="img-responsive" id="afCountries" src=
"img/african-countries/accra-ghana.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Accra, Ghana</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img alt="kigali" class="img-responsive" id="afCountries"
src="img/african-countries/kigali-rwanda.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Kigali, Rwanda</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img alt="durban" class="img-responsive" id="afCountries"
src="img/african-countries/durban-southafrica.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Durban, South Africa</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img alt="Johannesburg" class="img-responsive" id=
"afCountries" src="img/african-countries/Johannesburg-South_Africa.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Johannesburg, South Africa</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img alt="kenya" class="img-responsive" id="afCountries" src=
"img/african-countries/kenya.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Kenya</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href=
"#carousel-ex"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href=
"#carousel-ex"><span class=
"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">          </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to reproduce problem. I tried to reproduce the problem at Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/x9VUw3LOO6 with different images. I Googled some images with various sizes for testing, but the only time I had some square boxes in the carousel, was when the image wasn't found (I had the wrong URL address for the image). So if someone decides to have a look at the Bootply test, then please be aware those images were chosen by me (swiftly).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Similar to Jyrkim, your solution works for example editors like Bootply and JSFiddle. My only thought is that you're missing the fonts section of your bootstrap folder. `White Squares` is a placeholder for a character that can't be found in the current font type, like a special character in a custom font. It may render as `[]` instead of something like `*` or `&`. Make sure your folder structure in Bootstrap is set up as follows:

```
bootstrap
-> css
   -> bootstrap-theme.css
   -> bootstrap-theme.css.map
   -> bootstrap-theme.min.css
   -> bootstrap.css
   -> bootstrap.min.css
   -> theme.css
-> fonts
   -> glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
   -> glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
   -> glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
   -> glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
-> js
   -> bootstrap.js
   -> bootstrap.min.js
```

I would bet any money that the `fonts` folder is not there, or not linked properly. If your folder structure is the same as above, you can link the .css file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Hope that helps!

**Note**

Using the CDN version of the style sheet will cause this to not be an issue, but may increase load time.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't support Glyphicons but if you want to use Glyphicons with bootstrap versions> 4 than based on this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588852/17053552
Since I was using bootstrap 4.3.1v, I wasn't supposed to change the whole Bootstrap version or use any other icons or downloading extra files to just make icon work
I tried something like this:

1. In bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js check for icons

```
    icons: {
           previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
           next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
       }
```

2. In bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css, I changed the content
   From this:

```
     bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev::after{content:"Previous Month"} 
   bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next::after{content:"Next Month"}
```

To this:

```
    bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev::after{content:"previous"} 
    bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next::after{content:"next"}
```

and It worked for me.