# Bootstrap navigation arrows missing for datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I realize there were similar questions to this where the problem was the correct font family not being referenced.  However, in the version I am using, they don't use an icon for the navigation arrows, they use the html character code for the double-left and double-right arrows.

My html references -

```
<link href="Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type= "text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: 'linked',
            useCurrent: true,
            ignoreReadonly: true
        })
    });
</script>
```

Here is the relevant coding from the bootstrap-datepicker.js file -

```
    headTemplate: '<thead>'+
                      '<tr>'+
                        '<th colspan="7" class="datepicker-title"></th>'+
                      '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<th class="prev">&laquo;</th>'+
                            '<th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch"></th>'+
                            '<th class="next">&raquo;</th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</thead>',
    contTemplate: '<tbody><tr><td colspan="7"></td></tr></tbody>',
    footTemplate: '<tfoot>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<th colspan="7" class="today"></th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<th colspan="7" class="clear"></th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</tfoot>'
};
```

All I am getting is the same grey as the general header background, and then the normal blue "hover-over" as I would for any particular day on the calendar.

[image: Naughty datepicker]

I looked for conflicting ".prev" definitions in the other .css files, but didn't see any specific to tables, datepicker or headers.  I have also tried substituting coding using the glyphicons, same result.

My jfiddle -

[JFiddle Coding samples](https://jsfiddle.net/pxujfqjr/)

Comment: your sprite files, are they in the directory that bootstrap is looking for?

Comment: In a situation like this a fiddle is probably required so we can check for any conflicts in the various CSS and JS you're using.

Comment: You should include `glyphicons-halflings-regular` file

Comment: @demo - I do have that file in the fonts directory, and it does get referenced by the bootstrap.css.  However, since it's not using an icon from any font family, why is it needed?

When I use the html character coding (&laquo;) in the body of the page, it shows up fine, FYI.

Comment: @Robert C - I'll check on how to set that up and will edit when I it's done.  Thanks!

Comment: Added jfiddle link to question.  I'm not all that experienced with bootstrap or javascript, so if it's a mess, I apologize.

Comment: @AndrewMattson If you look at your logs, there are errors loading images associated with the prev/next.  It looks like jQuery UI is overriding `&laquo;` and `&raquo;` and trying to replace them with icons that don't exist.

Comment: @Robert C - can you submit that as the answer, so you get credit for it?  The  jquery-2.2.0.js file was looking for the ui image files.  I added the directory within the css directory, and added the associated images.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your provided Fiddle, it looks like jQuery UI is the problem.  It is overriding elements of your `.datepicker` class and replacing the text in `.prev` and `.next` with image-based icons with relative paths that aren't valid in your build.

Your solutions would be either add the appropriate images (which, based on your response to the comments above you have chosen), or ensure that jQuery UI isn't hooking into your Datepicker.

Comment: Adding the images was definitely the path less fraught with potential disaster, for someone as inexperienced with javascript as I am.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Loading jquery-ui css before font awesome css fixed it for me

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "01/01/1965",
    maxDate: "12/31/2005",
    startDate: "01/01/1965",
    endDate:    "12/31/2005",
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    autoclose: true
  });

  $('.prev i').removeClass();
  $('.prev i').addClass("fa fa-chevron-left");

  $('.next i').removeClass();
  $('.next i').addClass("fa fa-chevron-right");

});
```

Remove the class of the tag  on  and later assign a font-awesome arrow class

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because of the icons for these arrows are not found.

1. Go to **bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js** and search for **icons**

   ```
   icons: { time: "glyphicon glyphicon-time", date: "glyphicon glyphicon- 
   calendar", up: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up", down: "glyphicon glyphicon- 
   chevron-down", previous: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left", next: "glyphicon 
   glyphicon-chevron- right", today: "glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot", clear: 
   "glyphicon glyphicon- trash", close: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" },
   ```
2. Make sure these two classes have the style which their value appears on the list above

   ````
       .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev::after {
           content: "previous"; 
        }

       .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next::after {
           content: "next";
        } ```
   ````
3. Try to change glyhpicon to other icons if step 2 doesn't work